# Apply an operation/function to a ChunkedArray in pyarrow?

Tags: python, pyarrow

I'm sure this is in the documentation somewhere and I just haven't found it yet.
I have some data I'm reading in as part of a `parquet` dataset that includes a chunked array (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.ChunkedArray.html), which looks something like the following:

```
table = pa.table({'IDs': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D"], 'ChunkedArray':[[7,0,5,8,0],[7,9,1,9,4],[7,1,0,10,7],[8,3,4,0,5],[5,4,5,6,2],[0,5,5,1,6],[8,9,0,10,7],[0,5,10,5,10],[9,6,9,5,10],[8,7,7,3,6],[5,4,10,2,5]]})
```

I am trying to apply the `group_by` function to the arrays to get arrays of the maximum, mean, and most frequent values of each chunked array by ID.

Along the lines of:

```
IDs ChunkedArray
A   [7,9,5,10,7]
B   [8,4,5,6,5]
C   [9,9,10,10,10]
D   [8,7,10,3,6]

IDs ChunkedArray
A   [7,3.333333333,2,9,3.666666667]
B   [6.5,3.5,4.5,3,3.5]
C   [4.25,6.25,6,5.25,8.25]
D   [6.5,5.5,8.5,2.5,5.5]

IDs ChunkedArray
A   [7,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]
B   [NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]
C   [0,5,NaN,5,10]
D   [NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]
```

They can be either separate tables, or all part of the same table or dataframe (whichever is easier to implement), or have their own columns, but the actual dataset is extremely large so I was concerned this might lead to memory read issues.

Calling `aggregate` on the Chunked arrays directly throws errors because the data is a list:

```
>>> table.group_by("IDs").aggregate([("ChunkedArray", "mean")])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyarrow/table.pxi", line 5320, in pyarrow.lib.TableGroupBy.aggregate
  File "/usr/Python/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/acero.py", line 308, in _group_by
    return decl.to_table(use_threads=True)
  File "pyarrow/_acero.pyx", line 511, in pyarrow._acero.Declaration.to_table
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 144, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 121, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Function 'hash_mean' has no kernel matching input types (list<item: int64>, uint32)
```

And all my attempts at applying `flatten` on the `ChunkedArray` before or after calling the function have not been successful.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not that the array is chunked, it's that `ChunkedArray` is a *list* array. `ChunkedArray` can be flattened, but then won't be the same length as `IDs`. Assuming that is the goal (it's not entirely clear), the parent indices of a list array can be used create corresponding flat arrays.

```py
flat_table = pa.table({
   'ids': table['IDs'].take(pc.list_parent_indices(table['ChunkedArray'])),
   'values': pc.list_flatten(table['ChunkedArray']),
})

flat_table.group_by('ids').aggregate([('values', 'mean')])
```

**Update:**
Based on comments, it seems the list scalars are of fixed size (5), and are meant to represent columns themselves. To pivot a list array:

```py
columns = {f'c{i}': pc.list_element(table['ChunkedArray'], i) for i in range(5)}
pa.table(columns | {'IDs': table['IDs']})
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not what I'm looking for. That will produce the following:
  ids  values_mean
0   A          5.0
1   B          4.2
2   C          6.0
3   D          5.7

Which is the mean across the IDs for a single value. The columns across the array needs to be preserved. E.g.:
IDs ChunkedArray
A   [7,9,5,10,7]
B   [8,4,5,6,5]
C   [9,9,10,10,10]
D   [8,7,10,3,6]

It would almost be easier to split the chunked array into new columns I think, but I am not sure how that would be done or if it's memory efficient to do so.

Comment: I believe this will work.
That said, any suggestions on how to get the most frequent value?

Comment: Or for that matter, pass multiple columns to the argument at once?