# Frequency of A list in a Pyarrow Table

Tags: python, list, aggregate, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Find myself in an interesting conundrum, in that I need to compute the frequency of a series of lists by participant ID. Data looks not unlike the following:

```
test_table_orig = pa.table([
    pa.array(["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f"]),
    pa.array([[1,1,1,1], [2,0,1,2], [3,2,1,0], [4,3,2,1], [4,3,2,1], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [5,4,3,2], [5,4,3,2], [5,4,3,2], [5,4,3,2], [4,3,2,1], [6,5,4,3], [6,5,4,3], [8,7,6,5], [9,8,7,6], [7,6,5,4], [7,6,5,4], [7,6,5,4], [7,6,5,4], [10,11,12,13], [11,12,13,14], [12,13,14,15], [33,44,55,66], [22,33,44,55], [55,66,77,88], [22,33,44,55]])
], names=["ID", "ListData"])
```

Unfortunately, aggregation functions (e.g., `test_table_orig.group_by(['ID','ListData']).aggregate([('ListData','count')])`)

```
>>> test_table_orig.group_by(['ID','ListData']).aggregate([('ListData','count')]).to_pandas()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyarrow/table.pxi", line 5498, in pyarrow.lib.TableGroupBy.aggregate
  File "/home/usr/Python/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/acero.py", line 308, in _group_by
    return decl.to_table(use_threads=use_threads)
  File "pyarrow/_acero.pyx", line 511, in pyarrow._acero.Declaration.to_table
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 154, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 91, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Keys of type list<item: int64>
```

Don't seem to work on list datatypes.

However, if the data is a string:

```
test_table_string = pa.table([
    pa.array(["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f"]),
    pa.array(["[1,1,1,1]", "[2,0,1,2]", "[3,2,1,0]", "[4,3,2,1]", "[4,3,2,1]", "[1,2,3,4]", "[1,2,3,4]", "[1,2,3,4]", "[1,2,3,4]", "[1,2,3,4]", "[5,4,3,2]", "[5,4,3,2]", "[5,4,3,2]", "[5,4,3,2]", "[4,3,2,1]", "[6,5,4,3]", "[6,5,4,3]", "[8,7,6,5]", "[9,8,7,6]", "[7,6,5,4]", "[7,6,5,4]", "[7,6,5,4]", "[7,6,5,4]", "[10,11,12,13]", "[11,12,13,14]", "[12,13,14,15]", "[33,44,55,66]", "[22,33,44,55]", "[55,66,77,88]", "[22,33,44,55]"])
], names=["ID", "ListData"])
```

I'm able to get exactly what I need:

```
test_table_string.group_by(['ID','ListData']).aggregate([('ListData','count')]).to_pandas()
   ID       ListData  ListData_count
0   a      [1,1,1,1]               1
1   a      [2,0,1,2]               1
2   a      [3,2,1,0]               1
3   a      [4,3,2,1]               2
4   b      [1,2,3,4]               5
5   c      [5,4,3,2]               4
6   c      [4,3,2,1]               1
7   d      [6,5,4,3]               2
8   d      [8,7,6,5]               1
9   d      [9,8,7,6]               1
10  e      [7,6,5,4]               4
11  e  [10,11,12,13]               1
12  f  [11,12,13,14]               1
13  f  [12,13,14,15]               1
14  f  [33,44,55,66]               1
15  f  [22,33,44,55]               2
16  f  [55,66,77,88]               1
```

Except that each individual list has a little over 120 values with up to 12 characters or so per number (totaling ~ 2.4k characters per list) so I am not sure if this is possible.

Would anyone know a good way to get a summary like this of list datatypes?

Or know a good way (or if it's possible) to re-cast this type of data to a string?

Any suggestions at all are appreciated.

Comment: Do you lists always have the same size?

Comment: @0x26res, if you mean in the sense of array length, yes. Character, not sure.

Comment: If they have the same number of elements than yes you can pivot the table as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: test_table_orig.group_by(test_table_orig.schema.names).aggregate([([],'count_all')]) leads to a segfault when I call it on the actual data.

Comment: Can confirm that everything segfaults once you hit up to 27 columns from the data (including the ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks the same as ["Apply an operation/function ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77489901/). List columns of fixed size can be pivoted and then grouped by all columns.

```py
columns = {f'c{i}': pc.list_element(test_table_orig['ListData'], i) for i in range(4)}
pivot = pa.table({'ID': test_table_orig['ID']} | columns)
counts = pivot.group_by(pivot.column_names).aggregate([([],'count_all')])
```

Comment: Didn't realize you could add all of it to the grouping call.
If that's the case, what would be passed to `aggregate`?

Comment: test_table_orig.group_by(test_table_orig.schema.names).aggregate([([],'count_all')]) leads to a segfault when I call it on the actual data.

Comment: Can confirm that everything segfaults once you hit up to 27 columns from the data (including the ID).